# Non-distributed data structure in Hazelcast

Tags: java, caching, hazelcast, in-memory

The Hazelcast datastructures are by default distributed (replicated/accessible by any node in the cluster). Is it possible to make a datastructure as local or non-distributed, if desired so?

Context: We have the need to cache some data in-memory. It doesn't really need to be distributed but local to the node where it is inserted. We could choose not to use Hazelcast but the language datastructures directly (such as `java.util.List`). However, we would like to make use of the capabilities that Hazelcast offers, such as time-to-live.

Is it possible to specify if a datastructure should not be distributed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normally not a Hazelcast usecase, so even if you use a one-node-cluster you probably won't get the expected performance, since Hazelcast always serializes data. You might want to have a look at Google Guava as it might be better suited.

Comment: Thank you. Will take a look. We are already using hazelcast as a distributed cache in a multi-node cluster. Suggestion was to use it for "local data" as well and avoid bringing in new components/dependencies.